# How to go to parent window after opening a new window in php

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form onsubmit="window
     .open('paper.php?start_t=yes&pass_sub_id=<?php echo $qr1;?>',
            'print_popup',
            'width=1000,height=800');">
```

It will open a new window, when I click on submit on the newly opened window it will come back to parent page and will open a url.

Comment: I would use a modal window in the current one instead of opening a new window / tab.

Answer (score 0):

This code open a new window and listens to the event beforeunload to make a XMLHttpRequest and bring the new content...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <p>Click the button to open the new window.</p>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var newWindow = window.open("popup.htm", "popup", "width=200, height=100");
        console.log("LOG 1:"+newWindow.location.href);
        newWindow.addEventListener("beforeunload",function(event){
            loadNew();
        }, true);
    }
    function loadNew(){
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "popup.htm", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I did it this way because `window.location.href="newLocation.html"` didn't work for me...